# Widgets in separate file

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've set up pretty much all my HTML with `Widget` declarations (about 250 lines of code) and my Main.hs file is getting a little to big for my taste. So naturally, I tried to move the whole widget business to a new `Widgets.hs` file.

However, Yesod is somehow refusing to let me. The first thing I got was

```
Widgets.hs:17:30: error:
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Widget’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘WidgetT’ (imported from Yesod), ‘ToWidget’ (imported from Yesod)
```

for each and every single one of my `Widget` declarations. I tried importing `Widget` and `ToWidget`, leading to the next error:

```
Widgets.hs:11:1: error:
Failed to load interface for ‘Yesod.WidgetT’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Widgets.hs:12:1: error:
Failed to load interface for ‘Yesod.ToWidget’
Perhaps you meant Yesod.Core.Widget (from yesod-core-1.4.36)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

The Yesod book talks about `Widget` being just a type synonym:

```
type Widget = WidgetT MyApp IO ()
```

but I don't know how this might help me, or where to go from there. Do I need to do something with my `.cabal` file? I'm using the yesod-minimal stack template.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: The problem is that `MyApp` is only generated with mkYesod by Template Haskell, i.e. you need to import not only the Yesod library but your own module in which you define _your yesod_.

I believe Yesod has some scaffolding scripts to make this setup stuff easy, but I've never used them.

Comment: As for the library imports: you didn't write `import Yesod.WidgetT`, did you? That's not a module, only a type. the correct syntax is `import Yesod (WidgetT)`.

Comment: I tried both; neither works.

Comment: Well, `import Yesod (WidgetT, ToWidget)` _does_ work.

Comment: That did it. I moved the `data` declaration that `mkYesod` uses into a `DataDeclarations` file (where I keep my own types anyway), left the `mkYesod` and the `instance` declarations in `Main.hs` and put the `type Widget = WidgetT MyApp IO ()` in the `Widgets.hs` file. Finally, `import DataDeclarations` makes it work. Thanks a bunch =)